# I want to overwrite a file when there is a file with the same name. (C++ file.write)

Tags: c++

My code looks like this. 
I am using two buffers because somehow my buffer doesn't fit all data.
Anyways, I want my files to be overwritten every time I run the code,
but it won't be overwritten when there is a file with the same name.
So I have to delete the files before running. How can I change the code to overwrite files?

Btw I am getting the file name passed in my writeFile function
with char filename[] type.

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary| ios::app);
if (!myfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
}
myfile.write((char *)&(*buffer), 512 * 512 * depth);
myfile.write((char *)&(*buffer2), 512 * 512 * depth);

myfile.close();
```

Comment: Don't use the `ios::app` flag? You might want to read a little more about the open mode flags and what they do.

Comment: Thanks!! I really should take ur advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as you tell it. You have to remove the  `ios::app`.

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary); // <-- changes here
if (!myfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
}
myfile.write((char *)&(*buffer), 512 * 512 * depth);
myfile.write((char *)&(*buffer2), 512 * 512 * depth);

myfile.close();
```